# Separate string of JSONs into multiple rows PySpark

Tags: json, pyspark

I want to separate a string of JSONs in my dataframe column into multiple rows in PySpark. Example:

Input:

| id | addresses |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"city":null,"state":null,"street":"123, ABC St, ABC Square","postalCode":"11111","country":"USA"},{"city":"Dallas","state":"TX","street":"456, DEF Plaza, Test St","postalCode":"99999","country":"USA"}] |

Expected output:

| id | addresses |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"city":null,"state":null,"street":"123, ABC St, ABC Square","postalCode":"11111","country":"USA"} |
| 1 | {"city":"Dallas","state":"TX","street":"456, DEF Plaza, Test St","postalCode":"99999","country":"USA"} |

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example in your question, it is not clear what is the type of the `addresses` column and what type you need in the output column. So, let's explore different combinations.

- `addresses` column is of type `ArrayType`: in this case, you can use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html):

```py
df.select('id', F.explode('addresses').alias('address'))
```

The result is:

```bash
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |address                                                                                              |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{country -> USA, state -> null, city -> null, street -> 123, ABC St, ABC Square, postalCode -> 11111}|
|1  |{country -> USA, state -> TX, city -> Dallas, street -> 456, DEF Plaza, Test St, postalCode -> 99999}|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The type of the output column will be the same of the type of the items in the input column.

- `addresses` column is an `Array` of `StringType`, but you want your output to be a `StructTpye`: in this case, you can convert each string into a struct, using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, SparkSession, types as T

json_schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("city", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("state", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("street", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("postalCode", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("country", T.StringType()),
])

df_struct_from_array = (
    df
    .withColumn('address', F.explode('addresses'))
    .select('id',  F.from_json('address', json_schema).alias('address'))
)
```

The following dataframe is the result:

```bash
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|id |address                                          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{null, null, 123, ABC St, ABC Square, 11111, USA}|
|1  |{Dallas, TX, 456, DEF Plaza, Test St, 99999, USA}|
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The schema of `df_struct_from_array` is:

```bash
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- postalCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

- `addresses` column is of `StringType` and you want a `StructType` Column in output: in this case, you have to convert from JSON first and then explode:

```py
json_schema = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
    T.StructField("city", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("state", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("street", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("postalCode", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("country", T.StringType()),
]))

df_struct_from_str = (
    df
    .withColumn('addresses_conv', F.from_json('addresses', json_schema))
    .select('id', F.explode('addresses_conv').alias('address'))
)
```

This is what you get:

```bash
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|id |address                                          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{null, null, 123, ABC St, ABC Square, 11111, USA}|
|1  |{Dallas, TX, 456, DEF Plaza, Test St, 99999, USA}|
+---+-------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- postalCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```